# Automate script to run commands in a same process using Robot framework

Tags: python, shell, automation, robotframework

While using Robot framework , implement Write and Read .
When i execute a command like n2p-cli , I enter into this ">"
Then executing the commands like "help" its not executing

In short i want to execute commands even after entering into new application / process .